# setInterval jsf2.0 glassfish v3 and memory Leaks

Tags: jsf, glassfish-3, setinterval, cdi, out-of-memory

guys i'm new and i'm not english.
I have a problem with using js setInterval that simulate a user click, every X seconds, on submit button.
In the page there is only one h:form and h:commandButton.
I use a profiler and i see that the java.util.HashMap increase continuosly it's size.
After some hours the used heap size is growed a lot respect the start point.

Please help me, this problem make me crazy.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var timeoutId = window.setInterval( "userClick()" , 1000 );
        </script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <h:panelGroup id="testo">test</h:panelGroup>
    <h:form prependId="false" >
        <h:commandButton id="buttonId"
                         action="null"
                         value="Invia">
            <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render=":testo"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function userClick()
    {
        document.getElementById('buttonId').click();
    }
    </script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

---

**Update**: After 1 days the application crash again.
Now I have used only the setInterval but i have the heapDump generated by glassfish this is the screenshot but i'm unable to post it because my reputation is too low.
however java.lang.Object[] consume 20% of heap, java.util.HashMap$Entry[]18% and HashMap 10%
Any idea?

**Update**:
Hi, guys i have solved my problem and have found a bug in CDI dependency/injection.
I have solved my problem changing the Annotation @Named with @ManagedBean and this solve my problem.
In the example i have omitted the code because i think that CDI haven't bug.
Obviously the Bean annotated with @Named have request Scoped while the ApplicationScoped Bean doesn't produce the bug.
I'm relatively new with CDI, so where i must report the bug?

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the `setInterval` call and the code it's running.

Comment: This sends a request every second to the server, so you might want to look at how the request is handled. You might also want to up the interval timer, 1 second is very short considering the roundtrip might take longer than that.

Comment: If I increase the interval the memory grow slowly but after some days the server crash in outOfMemory.Obviously the web page must be open in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> After some hours the used heap size is growed a lot respect the start point.

Ok. But what memory usage do you get after garbage collection (GC)? I suggest turning on GC logging (`-Xloggc:file.log`) and maybe post some graph of the results here. Also make sure you're using a up to date version of GlassFish (3.0.1).

Comment: So without setInterval the HasMap used Memory increase of 40 Bytes each 10 seconds while with setInterval the memory increase of about 2Kb each 10 seconds.

Comment: @user451960 The problem is not really the `setInterval`, the problem is what actually occur on the server side when the particular request triggered every second is performed.

Comment: However i'm doing a simple chat application and i'm using Primefaces p:poll (it use setInterval) for updating the data.When i tested the application with users the application crash in outOfMemory after some hours. So without change in the code i have used Icefaces Push almost of setInterval. Now the application never crash. So I'm sure that setInterval is the problem.

Comment: @user451960 You need to look at the resulting difference from the server point of view.

Comment: I'm not an expert programmer, it's difficult to understand what may cause this problem.Now i'm trying to use setInterval without using the p:poll primefaces component. However i turn  on the GC logging.Thx for the suggest

Comment: @user: `setInterval()` is a JavaScript thingie which runs at the webbrowser and has absolutely no influence on webserver memory. It's the Java/JSF code logic running at the webserver which is causing the problems. As now it appears that server side logic which is listening on polls of Primefaces `p:poll` is the cause of the problem. How about Primefaces `p:push`? I'd suggest to report this issue to Primefaces guys.

Comment: p:push may be a solution (except athmosphere problem with glassfish), but i prefer icefaces push that work great. The problem of icefaces push is the connection timeout that however I set it in my web.xml is ignored (i need to report it too). I'm relatively new about primefaces so initially i think that the memory leaks was caused by my codes. In these day i think to report it to primefaces forum. With jsf 2.0 and primefaces i use Spring too but when i delete p:poll the problem is solved so i think that Spring doesn't make diference